# Fabric's cd context manager does not work

Tags: python, fabric

I have set up my development environment on a new PC and seems I am having strange error with Fabric. Its 'cd' context manager seems does not change the current directory, and thus a lot of my commands don't work. I have written the test and it showed me results I have not expected to get:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import local, run, cd

def xxx():
    with cd("src"):
        local("pwd")
```

Here are the results after running `fab xxx`:

```
[localhost] local: pwd
/home/pioneer/workspace/myproject
```

But instead of `/home/pioneer/workspace/myproject` there should be `/home/pioneer/workspace/myproject/src`, I think.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You're looking for [`lcd`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/api/core/context_managers.html?highlight=cd#fabric.context_managers.lcd) (`l` for local) rather than `cd` (which is remote).

Comment: Hmmm ... really, that's my fault, I've overlooked this. But, strange it worked with "cd" well until I moved to new PC.

Comment: I've found the problem - this was because of incompatibilities between Fabric 0.9 I had before and current 1.x